# line.strip between comment and variable

Tags: python, regex

I have the following line of code:

```
if line.lstrip().startswith('#%s' % debug_variable):
```

This makes a good match to the following line in a file:

```
#debug true
```

What I am trying to do is find a way of matching the following cases:

```
# key true
#  key true
#<tab>key true
```

i.e. any amount of space between the comment (#) and the key

So essentially, I need a regexp to act between the # and my %s variable

I have tried things like the following:

```
if line.lstrip().startswith('#\w%s' % debug_variable):
```

But not getting much luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to go with regex then `startswith` is not necessary.

```
if re.match(r'#\s*' + debug_variable, line):
```

or

```
if re.match(r'#[ \t]*' + debug_variable, line):
```

Note that `re.match` tries to match from the begining of the string so start of the line anchor `^` wasn't necessary.